# SQL - Is there a way to calculate a running total on a series of dates?

Tags: mysql, join, cumulative-sum

Given a list of events with date where 1 indicates something (e.g. student) joined a group and -1 indicates something left a group, is it possible to calculate group size by date in SQL? I have code that produces all dates in a range... that works when I run it on its own. Then I'd like to join in enrollment events by class and have a total of the number enrolled on each date. (+1 == class add, -1 == class drop).

I think I am missing something fundamental about how Joins and Grouping works in SQL.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4835/5/0

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE classes(`id` int, `name` varchar(7));
INSERT INTO classes(`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'math'),
    (2, 'english'),
    (3, 'sciene');

CREATE TABLE enrollment_changes(
  `class_id` int, 
  `change_date` date, 
  `change` int);
INSERT INTO enrollment_changes
    (`class_id`, `change_date`, `change`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-01-01', 1),
    (1, '2019-01-01', 1),
    (1, '2019-01-02', -1),
    (3, '2019-01-02', 1),
    (1, '2019-01-03', 1),
    (2, '2019-01-03', -1)
;
```

```
-- This gets me part way there... it produces the product of dates x classes 
SELECT 
  date_range.event_date, c.name
FROM 
  (SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) event_date 
    FROM
      (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
      (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
      (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
      (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
      (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
  ) AS date_range
  JOIN 
    classes c
WHERE 
  date_range.event_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-03'
;

-- This does not work at all... it reduces the output to a single record.
SELECT 
  date_range.event_date, c.name, SUM(e.change) AS 'NetEnrollment'
FROM 
  (SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) event_date 
    FROM
      (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
      (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
      (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
      (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
      (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
  ) AS date_range
  JOIN 
    classes c
  JOIN 
    enrollment_changes AS e
  ON
    e.change_date <= date_range.event_date
  AND
    e.class_id = c.id
WHERE 
  date_range.event_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-03'
;
```

Current result:

```
event_date   name   NetEnrollment
------------------------------------
2019-01-01   math      6
```

Desired result:

```
event_date   name      NetEnrollment
------------------------------------
2019-01-01   math      1
2019-01-01   english   0
2019-01-01   science   0
2019-01-02   math      1
2019-01-02   english   1
2019-01-02   science   0
2019-01-03   math      2
2019-01-03   english   1
2019-01-03   science   1
```

Comment: Not sure if i understand the desired result..  Why `2019-01-03   math      2` ? The 2 value for NetEnrollment there seams odd as the "same group"  `2019-01-03   english   1
2019-01-03   science   1` are still 1 for NetEnrollment i would also expected 2 there as `english` and `science` also has previous values just like `math` has ?

Comment: On the 1st, math has a net enrollment of 1. On the 2nd, there was no change to math so the net enrollment remains 1. On the 3rd, 1 student was added, for a net of 2. In my initial post I omitted the AND to tie enrollment event to class, which confused things.

Comment: Now i see, but it wil not work on the current dataset as there isn't a defined order in cases of duplicated values in the change_date column within class_id "groups"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT date_range.event_date, c.name, IFNULL(SUM(e.change), 0) AS 'NetEnrollment'
FROM (
  SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) event_date 
  FROM
    (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
    (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
    (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
    (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
) AS date_range JOIN classes c 
  LEFT JOIN enrollment_changes AS e ON e.change_date <= date_range.event_date AND  c.id = e.class_id
WHERE date_range.event_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-03'
GROUP BY date_range.event_date, c.name 
ORDER BY date_range.event_date, c.name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46bc10540df003a3bb317bf259cb0292)

---

Every day on the calendar table get joined with all classes (using `JOIN`). The encrollment changes get joined (using `LEFT JOIN`) to the day and specific class. Using `IFNULL` you can replace the `NULL` values with 0.

Using a `GROUP BY` just on the day results in one row per day. To get a row for every class per day you have to `GROUP BY` day and class name.

Comment: Nailed it! And I get it now. Thank you.